# WCF dying/stopping with objects still in memory

Tags: c#, wcf

My WCF service loads a lot of data like 3 million rows to SQL and other data insertion, but sometimes when the disk is busy or there is some taking more time, the WCF function stops doing that data insertion and stops, but the objects are still in the WCF memory. I don't know if the data insertion is messing up the service and everything freezes with the objects still in the WCF. There are no exceptions or anything like that thrown. The action stops like a total freeze, no disk activity after some disk activity for data insertion.

Anybody know what is going on?

Comment: -1 You really haven't explained your situation, your problem or anything. What do you mean by "loads a lot of data" or "action stops like a total freeze" or "the objects are still in the WCF memory"?

Comment: I have a values stored as static fields in the WCF that I keep. I do SQL insert and MongoDB insert. So I was assuming that if the service dies, all the memory objects in the static fields will reset, but in this case, the static values are there.

Comment: Perhaps some source code would help. Make sure you pare it down to the minimum to get the bug you are experiencing. Also read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80538/how-to-ask-questions-on-stack-overflow)

Comment: It is just a general issue. The SQL insertion is totally normal - the only difference is it is inserting millions of rows. This is just a general question on why a code will stop calling, but the service is still and live like it finished the processing, but it didn't finish the process (data insertion) without throwing any exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This course of action should provide you with the info you need to investigate the issue:

1. Set VS to break on throwing (`Debug` -> `Exceptions...` and beside `Common Language Runtime Exceptions` check `thrown`. It doesn't matter if you `catch` and exception or not, VS will break anyway. (As a bonus, you'll also see if you're inadvertently swallowing exceptions, which I suspect might be the issue)
2. Start a debugging session on your service (with the project open in VS, go to `Debug` -> `Attach to process` -> choose `w3wp.exe` on the remote machine ([You'll need Remote Debugging on the server: MSDN has the details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/y7f5zaaa.aspx))
3. Repro and see what happens (since something is going wrong, VS should stop and at least hint at what's wrong)